# xterm PS1 not working properly

Tags: bash, archlinux, xterm

for some reason I have found that xterm is not working properly as it should be, 
for example I was having a customized PS1 and now it only shows PC name and % like so `ehab%`, when I run `source .bashrc` I get what in PS1 var as a string, not having the matched colors or name `[\[\e[0;31m\]\u\[\e[m\] \[\e[0;36m\]\W\[\e[m\]]\$`. any idea why is that happening?

here is my .bashrc

```
#
# ~/.bashrc
#

# If not running interactively, don't do anything
[[ $- != *i* ]] && return

alias ls='ls --color=auto'

#PS1='[\u \W]\$ '
PS1='[\[\e[0;31m\]\u\[\e[m\] \[\e[0;36m\]\W\[\e[m\]]\$ '

export PATH="$PATH:$HOME/.rvm/bin" # Add RVM to PATH for scripting
export PATH="$PATH://opt/anaconda/bin" # Add anaconda to PATH
export VISUAL="vim"
export ECLIPSE_HOME="~/Downloads/eclipse/eclipse"
export PYTHONPATH="$PYTHONPATH:/usr/lib/python3.5/site-packages/"
#export TERM=xterm-color

export WORKON_HOME=~/.virtualenvs
source /usr/bin/virtualenvwrapper.sh

alias tmux="TERM=screen-256color-bce tmux"
```

.bash_profile

```
#
# ~/.bash_profile
#

source ~/.profile

[[ -f ~/.bashrc ]] && . ~/.bashrc

[[ -s "$HOME/.rvm/scripts/rvm" ]] && source "$HOME/.rvm/scripts/rvm" # Load RVM into a shell session *as a function*
```

Comment: probably one of the scripts you are sourcing is resetting `PS1`.

Comment: any idea how to debug that? last thing I did was setting up tmux for vim and I have changed my vimrc as well.

Comment: I'd simply put `echo "HERE:$PS1"` a few places in the `.bash_profile` and `.bashrc` to see where the value changed.

Comment: and by the way this is what I get when I `echo $PS1` -> `%m%#`

Comment: no - setting `PS1` with single-quoted strings works.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Got it!! I was working with bash shell and for some strangely weird reason it has been switched to zsh which has its own settings, so it's only require switching back to the bash shell to fix the problem.